# Set only clickable the items inside the GridView

Tags: android, gridview, onclick

I have a gridview with several items. They are clickable, but as you can see in the picture, when i press any part of the gridview item, everything is selected. My goal is to make only clickable the layout containig the image and textview (in each item of the GridView) .

Secondly, I have also noticed that the "clicked effect" appears behind the layout and not in front (check the picture). Is there any way of changing that?

[image]

the gridview is set as follows:

```
mItems.add(new GridViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.sman_package), getString(R.string.pick_package)));
mItems.add(new GridViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.sregister), getString(R.string.register)));
mAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, mItems);
// initialize the GridView
final GridView gridView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:

                break;
            case 1:

                break;
        }



    }
});
```

Where `GridViewItem` is

```
public class GridViewItem {
    public final Drawable icon;       // the drawable for the ListView item ImageView
    public final String title;        // the text for the GridView item title


    public GridViewItem(Drawable icon, String title) {
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;

    }
}
```

And `GridViewAdapter` is the following:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<GridViewItem> mItems;


    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, List<GridViewItem> items) {
        mContext = context;
        mItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            // inflate the GridView item layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false);

            // initialize the view holder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
            viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            //viewHolder.LayoutItem = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutItem);


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            // recycle the already inflated view
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // update the item view
        GridViewItem item = mItems.get(position);
        viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageDrawable(item.icon);
        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(item.title);

        return convertView;
    }

    /**
     * The view holder design pattern prevents using findViewById()
     * repeatedly in the getView() method of the adapter.
     *
     */
    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivIcon;
        TextView tvTitle;

    }
}
```

I have checked several posts but I still haven't found a proper solution. If any of you has an idea of how to solve it I would really appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

instead of setting onitemclicklistener on gridview set onclicklistener to ivicon and ivtitle in your gridviewadapter

Comment: No, this is not a solution :)